# Ramifications of replacing whole-home air purifier filter with different brand

Tags: hvac, air-quality

I would like to install a whole-home air purifier as I live in a city that does not have the best air quality. However, each company has different filters - some filter more than others and the costs vary drastically. From my understanding, the filters sit in a metal chassis that is attached to the furnace.

To save costs, I was thinking of getting a cheap metal chassis installed on my furnace and replacing the filter with a more high end one. The metal chassis will be a bit bigger than it should be, but I think this can be solved by framing the inside with printed metal pieces. I was just wondering if this could work in theory, or would I be facing issues?

Comment: I can't imagine that it _wouldn't_ work, but I don't know enough to make an answer on that. At a minimum, you'd need to make sure that the air flow of the replacement filter is at least as good as the air flow requirement of the system.

Comment: It might help if you were to [edit] your question to indicate the specific models involved.